# Can I use Domain Objects directly in Presentation Layer

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

I originally had the following setup:

Presentation Layer using --> Service Proxies generated via WCF --> Actual Services assembly (where proxy was generated from; hosted via IIS) --> Domain Layer (business logic) --> DAL

That was it initially but found out that Service and DAL should also access Domain Layer. Now I have a scenario where in the Presentation Layer, I have a datagrid that computes grades, and there are rules and computations which I believe should be in the Domain Objects.

My questions are:

1. Should the Presentation Layer reference the Domain Objects too? Is this common practice?
2. If yes, why would I need a Service Layer if I can directly access the Domain Objects? Or am I thinking in traditional n-Layer? If no, how would I go about this?

Feedback would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE/EDIT:**

@Yorro: Thank you for the response. In your Option 1, that is my problem. I can't send the values to be computed to the server. I need to have it reflected immediately in the UI.

For example, I have a domain object:

```
public class Grade
{
    List<CriterionGrade> children = new List<CriterionGrade>();

    public decimal FinalGrade
    { 
        get
        {
            decimal final = 0;
            foreach (CriterionGrade grade in CriterionGrades)
                total += line.LineTotal;

            return total;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<CriterionGrade> CriterionGrades
    {
        get { return children; } 
    }

    public void AddCriterionGrade(CriterionGrade grade)
    {
        children.Add(grade);
    }
}
```

What I am currently doing now is I have a DTO for Grade which includes the children but, being a DTO, no business logic. This DTO is on another machine along with Service Layer which I get a reference using WCF. Now my Presentation is WPF. So I bound the DTO to my DataGrid.

What I want to achieve is whenever the user changes the grade in the DataGrid, the FinalGrade rule should be enforced (this, the FinalGrade, is displayed in the UI too). Now since the proxies generated doesn't contain the Logic/Rules, I don't have access to that rule. And my requirement is I need the FinalGrade computed and shown on UI after any change.

Any ideas of how this is commonly resolved without duplicating the logic? The only thing I can think of is to reference the actual Domain object and put the computation in a service since the DataGrid is bound to the proxies but I am not sure if that is correct or ideal.

Comment: Are the grades, in the datagrid, stored in the database?

Comment: It can be if editing already saved grades, but it can be from user if new grades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Referencing other layers in the presentation**

The presentation can reference other layers, this is a common practice because some layered architectures implement IoC and DI, but that is another topic.

Even if the presentation references the other layers, that doesn't mean the presentation can directly access the domain layer. You still have to consider whether to commit to a clean cut logical separation (or loosely coupled multi-layer architecture). The presentation layer still communicates with the service layer, whether they are separated or not.

**Why use the service layer if you can directly access the domain?**

In DDD, you create a separate layer just for the domain right? You properly encapsulate and abstract this Domain Layer (using services) so that it becomes loosely coupled from the rest of the application (presentation), the purpose of this loosely coupled design is that any changes in the domain does not affect the entire application. **This is the main selling point of DDD.**

If you reference the domain all over the place, then changes in the domain requires you to change the rest of your application, like ripple effect. But if the layers are properly separated, each layer can evolved independently from each other, this is perfect for team based development.

If your presentation is physically separated from the domain (nTier architecture) and still want to adhere to DDD, I have two suggestions:

**Option 1**

You can create a "thin client". It is called "thin" because it does not do any computations or any hard work, the server does that for them. If the client wants to compute something, it just sends the parameters to the server (via Web API or WCF) then receives the computed result for display.

**Option 2**

If your parameters are too big (entire datagrid). You can include the service layer in your presentation. But the presentation and service are still separated, logically.

#### EDIT1:

Actually, you can send the entire datagrid in JSON format, and receive the final grade as response. If you are concerned about performance, ask yourself:

- how many users are we talking about here? hundreds of concurrent users?
- how big is the datagrid? hundreds of rows?
- Is it really slow as in more than 60 seconds per request? Have you even measured it?
- how big is the difference?

These are the questions that you should answer so you won't fall into the ["premature optimization" trap](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Please see my question updated as it is too long for a comment.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In the suggestion in your edit, this would mean that the user would need to enter all grades and send a request to compute the final grade, while my requirement needs that for every cell change (assume we have 50 rows 15 cols, the last col being FG for each row), the FG would be computed. I don't think this is premature optimization at all, just a functionality requirement. Again, sorry for replying late and thanks for giving the question some time.

Comment: @g_b - No, because that would hurt your usability. What I am suggesting is you need to create an event driven interface where every successful input of grade sends a request containing the work-in-progress datagrid. So every time the user inputs a grade, the final grade is automatically updated. From what I understand, you don't even need to send the entire datagrid, just the affected row.

Comment: OK, I will try what you said, also, I will be accepting this as the answer as the question is open for days and it seems like no one else is answering anymore, and also for the fact that your suggestion is quite reasonable. If I did have problems in performance, I'll just open another question. Thank you very much Yorro!

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

The "Service" you mentioned is called "Application Service" in DDD.

If your presentation layer is physically separated from the domain layer, you might want to add a "service" layer (WCF service, REST service etc) because you have no way to reference the domain models in this case.

But if your layers are only logically separated, then it's fine to reference the domain objects in the presentation layer (in this case, you can remove your "service" layer).

The "Application Service" layer is just a "[Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)". It can be used to hide the complexity of the domain layer by exposing much simpler application-specific APIs to your front-end applications (Websites, WPF Applications, etc). So actually there's no right or wrong to have it. You have to ask yourself, is your domain layer so complex that you have to add an "Application Service" layer to hide the complexity? I would prefer to "Keep It Simple Stupid" in the beginning.

BTW: I would prefer to use [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern in the presentation layer, especially when you are already using a MVVM framework like WPF. In this case, you handle UI logic in the View Model, and delegate domain logic to the domain layer.

Comment: OK, my Domain Layer is on a separate machine along with the Services, and you are right, I needed a WCF service layer to access it. But, what I'm having trouble solving is, in my datagrid, I need immediate compute and rule enforcement on change of cell values. I can't have the user enter all values then pass the whole datagrid values to a service layer for computations and rules enforcement, but I can't also reference the Domain Objs as they are on a separate machine. I don't want to create a duplicate of the rules and logic just so I can apply them to the Presentation. Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What about doing remote validation in the background? (In the background, senda request to the WCF service to do validation)

Comment: I think that would be too slow since data entry on each cell could only be seconds apart, and every cell change should compute using the business logic; the computation rules and logic wouldn't be able to keep up with the data entry. Nice idea though.

Comment: Yea. Maybe in the UI, you can validate the correctness of the data format, then for the business related validation, try to optimize the domain layer to make the response as fast as possible? Anyway, duplicate business logic in the UI is very dangerous cos any change to the business logic will break the app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try it out. I agree with what you said about duplicating code. I'll leave this question open for a few days, maybe more answers/suggestions would come up.