# Reusing business logic in a domain object to the presentation layer (or alternatives on how to achieve this)

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

I have a design problem in which I need a business logic to be also available in the presentation layer. The logic is currently in the domain layer. There is a service layer sitting on top of it which contains DTO of the domain objects. These DTOs are referenced by the WPF presentation layer in the form of WCF proxies. An example of domain object:

```
public class Grade
{
    List<CriterionGrade> children = new List<CriterionGrade>();

    public decimal FinalGrade
    { 
        get
        {
            decimal final = 0;
            foreach (CriterionGrade grade in CriterionGrades)
                final += grade.Grade;

        return final;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<CriterionGrade> CriterionGrades
    {
        get { return children; } 
    }

    public void AddCriterionGrade(CriterionGrade grade)
    {
        children.Add(grade);
    }
}
```

I need the totaling logic (among others), so in my UI, I can have a datagrid in which for every cell change, the total can be computed (think 50 rows 15 cols, the last col being FG for each row). I'm lost as to how to design this. I want to avoid having duplicate logic, and I am not sure if directly referencing domain objects is correct (from what I read, it is not).

I have already asked this ([Can I use Domain Objects directly in Presentation Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526297/can-i-use-domain-objects-directly-in-presentation-layer)) and accepted an answer (which is sending the rows affected to the service layer for processing of computation) but trying it out, it's really slow and a lot of quick changes happen in the datagrid so I think the computation should be local.

Any ideas on how one should implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the computation is pretty simple (a sum, basically), I wouldn't be shocked to see it reimplemented on the client side. Maybe the data grid component you use already has that feature, by the way.

The amount of domain logic you can transfer to the client side can be limited by security concerns - think web application where client code is out in the open. But although DDD is fundamentally strict about *layers*, I'm not sure it's that definitive with *tiers*. SPA-like applications with a thick client where the Domain layer would sit across client and server tiers cannot be ruled out from the DDD space that obviously, IMO.

An article on this : http://blog.jeffshurts.com/2008/10/rich-domain-model-use-on-both-client-and-server-in-an-ria/

Comment: Hi guillaume31. Sorry I haven't been clear. The code above was just a sample among other business logic. Actually, there are other complex computations to get the grades for other objects that should also be available in WPF datagrid (the criterion grades could also be computed), I just posted the above code for the sake of simplicity. I really want to avoid duplication if possible as maintaining it would be a headache.